# mask specific column object nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, masking

how to mask specific column (key) not full object in nodejs i'm using below method but does not success

i used below function but its mask all my key data. i want only specific key-name what i want mask
anyone help me this

```
  var obj = { cardNumber: "123456789123" ,abc: "hello world" ,efg: "hello friend" }
    function mask(obj){
    const masked = {};
      for (let key in obj) masked[key] = "*****";
      return masked;
}
masked: {
  "cardNumber": "*********",
  "abc": "*****",
  "efg":"***
```

}

what i want

```
masked: {
  "cardNumber": "1234*******123",
  "abc": "hello world" ,
  "efg":"hello friend" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the function which keys need to be masked.

```
var obj = { cardNumber: "123456789123" ,abc: "hello world" ,efg: "hello friend" };
var keysThatNeedToBeMasked={"cardNumber":true}
function mask(obj,keysThatNeedToBeMasked){
  for (let key in obj) 
  if(key in keysThatNeedToBeMasked)obj[key]="*******";
  return obj;
}
```

This will return {cardNumber:"******",abc: "hello world" ,efg: "hello friend" };